# Get time table from 4 attributes

Tags: java

I have an entity with opening and closing times and I have to list timetable in `HTML` label.

- Times can be empty.
- Ugly attribute names `getHorarioMIni` or `getHorarioTFin` cannot be changed due external `DB` relations and the auto-populating methods.

How to optimize this function:

```
public String getTimetable() {
    final String SEPARATOR = " - "; 
    final String NEW_LINE = "<br>"; 
    StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();

    if (nNoE(getHorarioMIni())) 
        sb.append(getHorarioMIni());
    if (nNoE(getHorarioMIni()) && nNoE(getHorarioMFin()))
        sb.append(SEPARATOR);
    if (nNoE(getHorarioMFin()))
        sb.append(getHorarioMFin());

    if ((nNoE(getHorarioMIni()) || nNoE(getHorarioMFin())) && (nNoE(getHorarioTIni()) || nNoE(getHorarioTFin())))
        sb.append(NEW_LINE); 

    if (nNoE(getHorarioTIni())) 
        sb.append(getHorarioTIni());
    if (nNoE(getHorarioTIni()) && nNoE(getHorarioTFin()))
        sb.append(SEPARATOR);
    if (nNoE(getHorarioTFin()))
        sb.append(getHorarioTFin());

    System.out.println(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}

private boolean nNoE(String toCheck) {
    return  toCheck != null && !toCheck.isEmpty();
}
```

Expected outputs (just commenting example constructor attributes):

```
08:00 - 12:00<br>15:00 - 18:00
15:00 - 18:00
08:00 - 12:00
08:00 - 12:00<br>18:00
```

**Extra** 
There is an easy way to achieve this? if only one of each group (`T` and `M`) filled?

```
08:00 - 18:00
```

---

## MCVE

To test it you can copy paste in a java class named `Main` and execute

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Silo silo = new Silo();
        System.out.println(silo.getHorarios());
    }
}


class Silo {

    public Silo() {
        // comment any time to check different outputs.
        this.horarioMIni = "8:00";
        this.horarioMFin = "12:00";

        this.horarioTIni = "15:00";
        this.horarioTFin = "18:00";
    }

    // M group (morning)    
    private String horarioMIni;
    private String horarioMFin;
    // T group (evening)    
    private String horarioTIni;
    private String horarioTFin;

    public String getHorarioMIni() {
        return horarioMIni;
    }
    public void setHorarioMIni(String horarioMIni) {
        this.horarioMIni = horarioMIni;
    }
    public String getHorarioMFin() {
        return horarioMFin;
    }
    public void setHorarioMFin(String horarioMFin) {
        this.horarioMFin = horarioMFin;
    }
    public String getHorarioTIni() {
        return horarioTIni;
    }
    public void setHorarioTIni(String horarioTIni) {
        this.horarioTIni = horarioTIni;
    }
    public String getHorarioTFin() {
        return horarioTFin;
    }
    public void setHorarioTFin(String horarioTFin) {
        this.horarioTFin = horarioTFin;
    }
    public String getHorarios() {
        final String SEPARATOR = " - "; 
        final String NEW_LINE = "<br>"; 
        StringBuilder sb  = new StringBuilder();

        if (nNoE(getHorarioMIni())) 
            sb.append(getHorarioMIni());
        if (nNoE(getHorarioMIni()) && nNoE(getHorarioMFin()))
            sb.append(SEPARATOR);
        if (nNoE(getHorarioMFin()))
            sb.append(getHorarioMFin());

        if ((nNoE(getHorarioMIni()) || nNoE(getHorarioMFin())) && (nNoE(getHorarioTIni()) || nNoE(getHorarioTFin())))
            sb.append(NEW_LINE); 

        if (nNoE(getHorarioTIni())) 
            sb.append(getHorarioTIni());
        if (nNoE(getHorarioTIni()) && nNoE(getHorarioTFin()))
            sb.append(SEPARATOR);
        if (nNoE(getHorarioTFin()))
            sb.append(getHorarioTFin());

        System.out.println(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private boolean nNoE(String toCheck) {
        return  toCheck != null && !toCheck.isEmpty();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Working around 'ugly' method names

Ok, so you realized you are constrained by the getter names due to some 'configuration-by-convention' features of your application/framework. If you think this can be fixed permanently in the future, and require a short-term workaround, you can consider having wrapper methods to... remind you to have the permanent fix sooner than later?

```
public String getHorarioTIni() {
    return getEveningStartTime();
}

// use this instead
public String getEveningStartTime() {
    // here's hoping you get to rename the field names too
    return horarioTIni;
}
```

Also, you mentioned the getters only, so I guess there's no excuse for `nNoE()`. :) Reading it as `isNotNullAndEmpty()` is easier on the brains.

## Avoiding code repetition

If you take a closer look at what you're doing now, it really boils down to these steps:

1. Define a 'duration description' (DD) as a start time, an optional separator, and an end time. The separator is required when both times are present.
2. Construct a DD for the AM session.
3. If there are DDs for both AM and PM sessions, insert the newline.
4. Construct a DD for the PM session.
5. Concatenate the DDs for both sessions with the optional newline in between.

Therefore, you can extract step 1 as a method:

```
// this can be made a class field
private static final String SEPARATOR = " - "; 

private static String createDescription(String startTime, String endTime) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Objects.toString(startTime, ""));
    if (isNotNullAndEmpty(startTime) && isNotNullAndEmpty(endTime)) {
        builder.append(SEPARATOR);
    }
    return builder.append(Objects.toString(endTime, "")).toString();
}
```

[`Objects.toString(Object, String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) is used here to make the `String` generation slightly more *expressive*.

The method body is now more compact, and hopefully more readable as a result:

```
public String getTimetable() {
    final String NEW_LINE = "<br>"; 
    String morningDuration = createDescription(getMorningStartTime(), getMorningEndTime());
    String eveningDuration = createDescription(getEveningStartTime(), getEveningEndTime());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(morningDuration);
    if (!morningDuration.isEmpty() && !eveningDuration.isEmpty()) {
        builder.append(NEW_LINE); 
    }
    return builder.append(eveningDuration).toString();
}
```